# Pass javascript variable by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameter-passing

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(lastmsgID); // fail display the value (my problem is here, please help)
        function myfunction()
        {
            jQuery.get("usermessage.php, function(data) {
               document.write(lastmsgID); //success display the value
            });
        };
</script>
```

usermessage.php

```
<?php $latestmsgid= "lovelovelove";
echo("<script type='text/javascript'>\n"); // pass php varible to javascript global variable lastmsgID
echo("lastmsgID = '". $latestmsgid  ."';\n");
echo("</script>"); 
?>
```

From my codes above, I declare global javascript variable `lastmsgID` on usermessage.php file. Then I used jQuery.get get the value of variable. Now my problem is I can only get the variable value inside myfunction() function, how can I pass the value of variable from the function to outside the function?

#### Update:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function myfunction()
        {
            jQuery.get("usermessage.php, function(data) {
               var test=data
               document.write(test); //success display the value
            });
        };

        document.write(test); // fail display the value because it is outside the function. (my problem is here, please help)
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`usermessage.php` contains an HTML `<script>` object, but `index.php` never does anything with the HTML it receives back from the AJAX call (`data`). You'd have to append the received HTML to the primary DOM.

Instead I recommend that `usermessage.php` returns the lastMsgID in plain text (or JSON), and then you have that in the variable `data`.

**Update**

You have since stated a requirement to access the retrieved value from the enclosing scope. Do this by creating a variable that's "more global", and setting its value accordingly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var MyVariable = ''; // global variable: changes to it will be global too

    function myfunction() {
        jQuery.get("usermessage.php, function(data) {
           MyVariable = data;
        });
    };

    document.write(MyVariable);
    /* ^ this will work, but not quite here. it'll show you the value
       ONLY if you write this line somewhere so that it executes *after*
       the jQuery.get call has completed. */
</script>
```

Comment: I can't use data to retrieve the variable because the data is already used for retrieving a list other messages. Is there any other way to get the variable value without using data?

Comment: @zac1987: No, `data` is how you should do it. If `data` already carries information, then just add `lastMsgID` to the list of things that `data` carries. If `data` were a JSON array/object then this would be easy.

Comment: okay, i follow what you told. I use data to retrieve the variable. Here is my codes : document.write(data); myfunction(){ jQuery.get("usermessage.php", function(data) { document.write(data); }); } but it is still the same, i can display the value of variable "data" inside the function only, i cannot display it outside the function. How to display it outside the function? – zac1987 1 hour ago

Comment: @zac1987: What does "outside the function" mean for you? If you have previously declared a variable as existing in an encapsulating scope, then you can use the assignment operator (`=`) to give that variable the new value from `data`.

Comment: "outside the function" is mean i document.write(variable) after closing the function. I have posted new answer to show u the example, please refer to the new answer. Thanks.

Comment: @zac1987: It would have been better to edit the question, as you're not answering anything. Anyway, the above stands. See my edit.

Comment: @zac1987: Well "it is not working" is a totally useless thing to say, as the approach _does_ work for millions of people around the world. Did you bother to read and understand the comment in it? If you can come up with a proper error description then feel free to file a new question. As it stands, do you have the answer to this original question?

Comment: I did read the comment and understand it. I call the function myfunction(); at first, then only i document.write(MyVariable); it is not working. You said your codes does work for million of people, did you actually tested your code? Because I did test your code, so I know your codes cannot work. <script type="text/javascript">MyVariable = '';
function aaaa()
{
    jQuery.get("usermessage.php", function(data) {            
    MyVariable = data;
    });
};

aaaa();
    document.write(MyVariable);</script>

Comment: Please see the line aaaa(); document.write(MyVariable); it mean the page will execute function aaaa() first, then only execute document.write. As your comment said the document.write will executes *after* the jQuery.get call has completed. */ Is it possible the page execute document.write before jquery finish fetch the data from usermessage.php? If yes, how can I make sure jquery finish fetch data, then only execute document.write?

Comment: @zac1987: Yes, exactly that. `$.get` is an _asynchronous_ call, so the function `aaaa()` completes _before_ the HTTP request completes! The inner function `function(data) { ... }` is a _callback_ that fires later when the request completes, but the rest of your code just continues on in the background regardless. `$.get` is a shorthand for `$.ajax` with the `async` parameter automatically set to `true`. You can force a simpler _synchronous_ request like: `$.ajax(url: "usermessage.php", success: function(data) { ... }, async: false);`

Comment: @zac1987: See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Answer (score 0):

PHP

```
<?php
$latestmsgid = Array("id" => "lovelovelove");
echo json_encode($lastmsgid);
?>
```

JS

```
var ID;

$.getJSON("usermessage.php", function(json) {
    ID = json.id;
});
```